# json.dumps gives me AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I am getting this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I know that it is my json.dumps that triggers the error. Here is my code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os
import datetime
import json

SUNDAY = 6
SATURDAY = 5

weekdayBookingTimes = ["10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00", "12:30", "13:00","13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00"]

def sendBookingForDate(request):
    dateToFetchBookings = request.GET.get('date','')
    #Check if date is SUNDAY
    if checkDayOfWeek(dateToFetchBookings) == SUNDAY:
        pass

    #Check if day is Saturday
    elif checkDayOfWeek(dateToFetchBookings) == SATURDAY:
        if os.path.isfile((dateToFetchBookings+".txt")):
            pass #tbt
        else:
            createBookingsForSaturday(dateToFetchBookings)
    #Check if day is normal day
    else:
        if os.path.isfile(dateToFetchBookings+'.txt'):
            pass
        else:
            createBookingsForNormalDays(dateToFetchBookings)

    with open('/home/MScissorss/mysite/mysite/'+dateToFetchBookings+'.txt') as f:
        bookingsToSend = json.load(f)
    #return HttpResponse(dateToFetchBookings)
    return json.dumps(bookingsToSend)


def checkDayOfWeek(date):
    tempDateStorage = date.split('-')

    year = int(tempDateStorage[0])
    month = int(tempDateStorage[1])
    day = int(tempDateStorage[2])

    return datetime.datetime(year,month,day).weekday()


def createBookingsForSaturday(date):

    normalBookings = {}

    for x in range(0,11):
        normalBookings[x] = {"bookingTime":weekdayBookingTimes[x], "booked":"false", "bookieName":"", "bookieNumber":""}

    with open('/home/MScissorss/mysite/mysite/'+date+'.txt', "w") as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(normalBookings))

def createBookingsForNormalDays(date):
    #Test data

    bookings = {}

    for x in range(0,17):
        bookings[x] = {"bookingTime":weekdayBookingTimes[x], "booked":"false", "bookieName":"", "bookieNumber":""}

    with open('/home/MScissorss/mysite/mysite/'+date+'.txt', "w") as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(bookings))
```

Check the end of the first function. That is where i do the return. I also thought that my dictionary was wrongly formatted, but i checked and it looks good:

```
{
"0": {"bookingTime": "10:00", "booked": "false", "bookieName": "", "bookieNumber": ""},
"1": {"bookingTime": "10:30", "booked": "false", "bookieName": "", "bookieNumber": ""}, 
"2": {"bookingTime": "11:00", "booked": "false", "bookieName": "", "bookieNumber": ""}, 
"3": {"bookingTime": "11:30", "booked": "false", "bookieName": "", "bookieNumber": ""}
}
```

The return that is commented above json.dumps works well. I get no errors when running that. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

**UPDATE - Full traceback added**

```
2018-11-15 23:53:05,718: Internal Server Error: /getBookings/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MScissorss/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/MScissorss/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/MScissorss/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Which call is getting the error?

Comment: FYI, you can use `json.dump(x, file)` instead of `file.write(json.dumps(x))`

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from `json.dumps()`? Post the full traceback.

Comment: When I search for that error message, other questions are getting it from `json.load`, not `json.dumps()`.

Comment: I am fairly certain that it has to do with json.dumps() because when i use the commented 'return' just above my json.dumps() in sendBookingForDate the error is gone. Let me rephrase with what i thought the problem was. I think the problem lies in how i send my 'JSON' back.

Comment: The line with the error appears to be trying to get an HTTP header from a `response` object. But for some reason `response` is a string rather than an object.

Comment: I think you shouldn't be returning JSON, you should be returning a `response` object.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar pointed out in the comments. All i needed to do was to change my return from  `return json.dumps(bookingsToSend)` to `return JsonResponse(bookingsToSend)`